# Findall items in one list matching items in another list's VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have 2 List's

1.SelectUsersList(Lists of SelectUsersGrid) which contains Users (String) and there status(Integer).
   2. SearchList(Lists of SearchListItem) ( Integer)

Findall items in one lists matching items in another list/lists( there can be multiple lists also)

I want search in SelectUsersList List which matches each & every item of SearchListItem,Working on LINQ Query in VB.

Tried Various Queries but nothing works

```
Input List SelectUsersList
{{0 ,"test1"},
{1 ,"test2"},
{1 ,"test3"},
{2 ,"test4"},
{3 ,"test5"},
{0 ,"test6"},
{1 ,"test7"},
{2 ,"test8"}


OutputList 

{{0 ,"test1"},
{1 ,"test2"},
{1 ,"test3"},
{0 ,"test6"},
{1 ,"test7"},
```

Following is code which i have tried till now.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions              
Public Module Module1
Public Class SelectUsersGrid

    Private _userStatus As Integer
    Private _firstName As String

    Public Property UserStatus() As Integer
        Get
            Return _userStatus
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _userStatus = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property FirstName() As String
        Get
            Return _firstName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _firstName = value
        End Set
    End Property
 End Class

 Public Class SearchListItem

    Private _userStat As Integer

    Public Property userStat() As Integer
        Get
            Return _userStat
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _userStat = value
        End Set
     End Property
 End Class

    Public Sub Main()

     'Your code goes here
           Dim allUserList As New List(Of SelectUsersGrid)
            allUserList.Add(New SelectUsersGrid with {.userStatus = 0 ,.firstName="test1"})
            allUserList.Add(New SelectUsersGrid with {.userStatus = 1 ,.firstName="test2"})
            allUserList.Add(New SelectUsersGrid with {.userStatus = 1 ,.firstName="test3"})
            allUserList.Add(New SelectUsersGrid with {.userStatus = 2 ,.firstName="test4"})
            allUserList.Add(New SelectUsersGrid with {.userStatus = 3 ,.firstName="test5"})
            allUserList.Add(New SelectUsersGrid with {.userStatus = 0 ,.firstName="test6"})
            allUserList.Add(New SelectUsersGrid with {.userStatus = 1 ,.firstName="test7"})
            allUserList.Add(New SelectUsersGrid with {.userStatus = 2 ,.firstName="test8"})

            Dim searchList As New List (Of SearchListItem)
            searchList.Add(New SearchListItem with {.userStat = 0})
            searchList.Add(New SearchListItem with {.userStat = 1})


            For Each item As SelectUsersGrid In allUserList
                  Console.WriteLine(item.UserStatus)
            Next 
    ' Search items in SelectUsersGrid matching to searchList

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Why this is neagtive if no reasoning is given

Comment: Perhaps because it is poorly formatted and bad grammer? What does "search in `SelectUsersList` `List` which matches each & every" mean? What is `SearchListItem`? Can you show sample input and output? Can you show VB types? How can a single member of `SelectUsersList` match every member of `SearchListItem`? How can `SearchListItem` have members?

Comment: `Dim results = allUserList.Where(Function(usr) searchList.Any(Function(st) st.userStat = usr.UserStatus)).ToList()`. If this is what you mean.

Comment: In your code comment, did you mean "Search items in allUserList" and not SelectUsersGrid? What does "matching to searchList" mean in that context?

Comment: @NetMage I have edited question

Comment: @Jimi Your response seems to be correct, but there are multiple list's to be search in List. Would we have to give same statement multiple times.

Comment: In above same question say we have another List named "searchfirstNameList" with just firstnames in it. So want to search both lists i.e. searchList (field:- userStat) and  searchfirstNameList (field:- firstName) to be searched inside allUserList. If that's makes sense.

Comment: You just *hinted* that you may have more than one list with search items, but you didn't define if and how these List or the search results are related. i.e., if you want to have a resulting list that is the `Union()` of the results of multiple search criteria or `Distinct()` elements from all the sub-lists or multiple lists that contain values from one list `Except()` the values of the others of if you need to `GroupBy()` the overall results using some other criteria.

Comment: @Jimi Any good working examples links ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a custom constructor to the `SelectUsersGrid` to make it a bit easier to create New instances to add to the `allUserList`.

I got rid of the `SearListItem` class. It seemed sort of silly since it was a class with just one property of a built in type. Changed the `searchList` to `List(Of Integer)`.

I displayed the `allUserList` with an interpolated string which became available to vb.net in Visual Studio 2015. In older versions you can use `String.Format`.

Then comes the line provided by @Jimi in comments. I changed it just a bit since `searchList` is now a `List(Of Integer)`.

The results is a `List(Of SelectUsersGrid)`. You can see this by holding your cursor over results in the code window. I loop through this list to show the contents of the list.

This is showing `Form.Load` since I am in a WinForms app. The code will be just as happy in `Sub Main`.

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim allUserList As New List(Of SelectUsersGrid)
    allUserList.Add(New SelectUsersGrid(0, "test1"))
    allUserList.Add(New SelectUsersGrid(1, "test2"))
    allUserList.Add(New SelectUsersGrid(1, "test3"))
    allUserList.Add(New SelectUsersGrid(2, "test4"))
    allUserList.Add(New SelectUsersGrid(3, "test5"))
    allUserList.Add(New SelectUsersGrid(0, "test6"))
    allUserList.Add(New SelectUsersGrid(1, "test7"))
    allUserList.Add(New SelectUsersGrid(2, "test8"))

    Dim searchList As New List(Of Integer)
    searchList.Add(0)
    searchList.Add(1)

    Console.WriteLine("All User List")
    For Each item As SelectUsersGrid In allUserList
        Console.WriteLine($"User Status {item.UserStatus}, First Name {item.FirstName}")
    Next
    Dim results = allUserList.Where(Function(usr) searchList.Any(Function(st) st = usr.UserStatus)).ToList()
    Console.WriteLine("Output list")
    For Each item In results
        Console.WriteLine($"User Status {item.UserStatus}, Name {item.FirstName}")
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

The following class uses auto-implemented properties. You can read about this feature at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/auto-implemented-properties

```
Public Class SelectUsersGrid
    Public Property UserStatus As Integer
    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Sub New(Stat As Integer, Name As String)
        UserStatus = Stat
        FirstName = Name
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem as shown seems simple enough.

Create a `HashList` to hold the desired `UserStatus`s:

```
Dim match = searchList.Select(Function(s) s.userStat).ToHashSet
```

Extract the Users from `allUserList` where their `UserStatus` is in the `HashList`:

```
Dim ans = allUserList.Where(Function (u) match.Contains(u.UserStatus)).ToList()
```